# How can I create time index df without date in pandas of python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

I want to create  time index df without date like this:

```
          2019/10/01  2019/10/02

00:00:00
00:00:01
00:00:02
00:00:03
...
23:59:59
```

How can I do this df?
Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Have you done any research, or tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have `date_range` , just need using `time` to only select the time

```
idx = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=24*60*60, freq='S').time


df.index = idx
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
df.index = pd.date_range(start='00:00:00', end='23:59:59', freq='S').time
```